# Calculate MBProgressHUD download progress

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage, mbprogresshud

Im trying to calculate download progress, so the bar start moving until the image is fully downloaded and then disappear , but it keeps on showing without even moving the indicator of progress. I am using SDWebimage progress to get the value of progress.

```
let url = NSURL(string: (array[indexPath.row][0] as? String)!)
cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, options: nil, progress: { (value1, value2) -> Void in

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

    self.HUD = MBProgressHUD(view: self.mycollectionView)
    self.view.addSubview(self.HUD)

    self.HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.AnnularDeterminate
    self.HUD.delegate = self
    self.HUD.show(true)
    var x : Float = Float(value1)
    self.HUD.progress = x
        var progress : Float = 0
        while (progress < x){
            progress += 0.1
            self.HUD.progress = progress
        }

      })

    }, completed: block)
```

Also I'm getting the following error :

```
<Error>: void CGPathAddArc(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, bool): invalid value for start or end angle.
```

The values comes to be when done the progress is :

```
progress:32477.0
```

Comment: could just be me, but your setting the progress to x (which is value1) in `self.HUD.progress = x` from the get go...so naturally it will start with the value you define, then your trying to set it to `var progress` after that

Comment: @soulshined, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to get your expected output using following code :

```
var HUD = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate

let url = NSURL(string: "urlString")
imageView.sd_setImageWithPreviousCachedImageWithURL(url, andPlaceholderImage: nil, options: nil, progress: { (value1, value2) -> Void in
       var progress = Float(value1)/Float(value2)
       HUD.progress = progress
}, completed: nil)
```

Hope this give you a start.

Comment: i will try it in a bit ! :)

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion @AaoIi you were setting your progress to value 1 which based off your example was the total length.